# jquery load script on click

Tags: jquery, external

I'm attempting to load a javascript script from another site with this code but it isnt working!

```
    $("#random").click(function(){
        $.getScript("http://www.themoviequotes.com/widgets/javascript?n=1&amp;l=1&amp;g=3");
    });
```

I have a div with an id of "movie" in which i'm trying to load the content into from the above script!

Comment: do you think the url is correct for sure??? i typed it directly and it didn't return me any thing??

Comment: absolutely, this the current HTML: <div id="movie">
    <script src="http://www.themoviequotes.com/widgets/javascript?n=1&amp;l=1&amp;g=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </div>

Comment: That [URL](http://www.themoviequotes.com/widgets/javascript?n=1&amp;l=1&amp;g=3) returns an empty page.

Comment: change the url , its working now , remove &amp;stuff...and make it proper querystring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `text/html` mode, `<script>` elements are intrinsically CDATA. Thus `&amp;` means `&amp;` and not `&`.

Do not use HTML entities inside `<script>` elements.

(If you are writing XHTML and serving it as text/html, then the [guidance on XHTML media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/) with special attention for the section on [embedded style sheets and scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).)

Since you have replaced `&` with `&amp`, you are fetching data from a URL that the server doesn't recognize.

However, even if you did change that, it still wouldn't work. The script, which for some reason is being served as `text/html` instead of `application/javascript`, contains a `document.write` statement. This writes to the end of the document (so it is useless for replacing a section of the page) if the document is still open for appending, or replaces it entirely otherwise.

`jQuery.load` wouldn't help since that expects some content to drop into an element (not a script to execute) and (as far as I know) has no cross-domain capabilities (which only work in very new browsers and only with servers which send the right HTTP headers).

Comment: That makes sense, am i using getScript correctly, should i use load(), i'm trying to replace the current content with this content everytime the user presses "random"

Comment: @ben , getscript just gets the javascript from the specified location and adds to head section

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, at the moment, it works but the page has to be refreshed. Is there no way i could get new content from this URL without refreshing the page

Comment: Not from the client. You could proxy the data through a program running on your own server, and then use `jQuery.load`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#random").click(function(){
    $.getScript("http://www.themoviequotes.com/widgets/javascript?n=1&l=1&g=3");
});
```

The URL was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your url is wrong

remove &

http://www.themoviequotes.com/widgets/javascript?n=1&n=l=1&g=3