# Changing Javascript method to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following Jquery calling a Javascript method

```
$j("a.Pinterest").attr("href", "javascript:void(addScript());");
```

And this is the Javascript Method

```
   function addScript() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=' + Math.random() * 99999999);
    return document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to have it all in Jquery ?

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: hmm, writing some code now, pls hold on abit

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881164/loading-an-external-script-after-page-load-with-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441142/load-external-js-file-with-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624366/dynamically-load-external-js-and-write-response-to-a-div, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361033/jquery-load-script-on-click

Comment: Instead of injecting inline JavaScript with jQuery, use a jQuery click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j("a.Pinterest").attr("href", "javascript:void(addScript());");
```

Please don't do this.  I suggest using a click handler.

```
$j("a.Pinterest").click(addScript);
```

And then in your `addScript` you can use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load the script.

```
function addScript(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $j.getScript('http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js');
}
```

Comment: Finally.  +1 for nuking that inline garbage.

Comment: This works fine but how can I add the link cursor when hovering over the selected link

Comment: @StevieB: You need to give it something as the `href` attribute.  Try `$j("a.Pinterest").attr("href", "#");`, or add `href="#"` to the link in the HTML.

Comment: Is this a good solution to ?     $j("a.Pinterest").css('cursor', 'pointer');

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript("http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
     console.log( textStatus );
 })
```

edit: I didn't try this, I just took your address and threw it in the getScript demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addScript() {
      return $('<script/>',{
                          'type':'text/javascript',
                          'charset':'UTF-8',
                          'src':'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=' + Math.random() * 99999999 
              }).appendTo("body")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements in jQuery using the $ selector.

```
$('<script></script>')
```

jQuery is also chainable, so you can have this:

```
$('<script></script>')
    .attr({
        'type' : 'text/javascript',
        'charset', 'UTF-8',
        'src' : 'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=' + Math.random() * 99999999)
     })
     .appendTo(whatever)
```

If you're doing conditional script loading, you might want to take a look at the [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) library.

I would question why you're dynamically added a script to the page on a button click. Seems like you would want the script ready and waiting for the user to click. If you're worried about load time, but the script tag at the bottom of the page to defer the loading.

Comment: I just wanted to hide the href attribute from the mark up, since the mark up has to go into content editor for a cms and I didnt want users to mess with it